# Test Symfony 2 bundle with Guzzle API client with phpspec

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpspec

Good morning!

I have recently created a Symfony 2 bundle that integrates with a third party API.
I have used Guzzle with the awesome service description to create the client and call the API.

Now I want to improve the quality and add some testing to it. After some reading I came up to use phpspec for the functional testing of the client and Behat for the behavior.
I have read that you can mock the API responses but I can’t figure out how. Though phpspec has a mocking library inside (prophecy), I can’t find any examples how to mock the responses in prophecy.

I have my spec created with

```
bin/phpspec desc NewFusion/Bundle/HyperMediaBundle/Service/VehicleService
```

And it has created my spec class in the `Bundle/spec/` folder.

```
<?php

namespace spec\NewFusion\Bundle\HyperMediaBundle\Service;

use PhpSpec\ObjectBehavior;
use Prophecy\Argument;

class VehicleReferenceDataServiceSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function it_is_initializable()
    {
        $this->shouldHaveType('NewFusion\Bundle\HyperMediaBundle\Service\VehicleReferenceDataService');
    }

    function it_should_return_make_name() {
        $this->getMake(array('makeCode' => 1))->shouldReturn(TRUE);
    }
}
```

This is the response I want the mock with this test:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate
>   Connection: Keep-Alive
>   Content-Type: application/vnd.siren+json; charset=UTF-8
>   Date: 12 Feb 2014 07:43:00 GMT
>   Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT, 0
>   Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Server: Jetty(8.y.z-SNAPSHOT)
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Via: 1.1 test.local
>
> {
>       "class": [
>           "Make"
>       ],
>       "properties": {
>           "makeCode": "1",
>           "name": "Alfa Romeo"
>       },
>       "links": [
>           {
>               "rel": [
>                   "self"
>               ],
>               "href": "https://test.local/v1/api/vehiclereferencedata/make/1"
>           },
>           {
>               "rel": [
>                   "models"
>               ],
>               "href": "https://test.local/make/1/model"
>           }
>       ]
>   }

I hope someone will get me on track :)

Comment: Hmmm i have made some progress .. 
I have to inject the client and then use the guzzle mock plugin to mock the response. regarding http://robinvdvleuten.nl/blog/mock-guzzle-responses-in-symfony-tests/ and then use the methods from phpspec the test / validate the response.

Comment: PhpSpec is not a functional testing tool. It is a unit testing tool. Besides, it's a bit harder to use it to write tests after the fact (as opposed to tdd).

Comment: Yeah i know .. i was mixing the concepts with Behat.
i'm refactoring a bit now so my servicebuilder can be injected in to the spec file. 
afterwards i'll refactor my test :)